# Looping inside a Postgres UPDATE query

Tags: arrays, postgresql, random, sql-update, generate-series

(Postgres 10.10) 
I have the following fields in *my_table*:

```
loval INTEGER 
hival INTEGER 
valcount INTEGER 
values INTEGER[]
```

I need to set *values* to an array containing *valcount* random integers each between *loval* and *hival* inclusive. So for:

```
loval: 3 
hival: 22 
valcount: 6
```

I'm looking to set *values* to something like:

```
{3, 6, 6, 13, 17, 22}
```

I know how to do this with an inefficient "loop through the cursor" solution, but I'm wondering if Postgres has a way to do a looping computation inline.

Note: I looked at generate_series, but I don't think it produces what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generate_series()` is indeed the solution:

```
update my_table
  set "values" = array(select (random() * (hival - loval) + loval)::int 
                       from generate_series(1, valcount));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fa4eaa2f363c7812fe273792fb6d1b0c)

---

Note that `values` is a reserved keyword, it's not a good idea to use that as a column name.