# Looping Inside a Postgres UPDATE Query - Part 2

Tags: postgresql

NOTE: This is very similar to, but not the same as my other recent question at [Looping inside a Postgres UPDATE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431856/looping-inside-a-postgres-update-query). The answer provided on that question works perfectly, but the client wants each value calculated using a specific formula rather than a randomized selection to enforce an even distribution.

(Postgres 10.10) 
I have the following fields in *my_table*:

```
loval INTEGER 
hival INTEGER 
valcount INTEGER 
vals INTEGER[]
```

I need to set *vals* to an array containing *valcount* - 2 integers (loval and hival are included in the final array) each calculated as follows using n as a loop counter running from 2 to valcount-1:

```
loval + (n - 1) * ((hival - loval) / (valcount- 1))
```

So for:

```
loval: 3 
hival: 22 
valcount: 6
```

I'm looking to set *vals* to:

```
{3, 7, 11, 14, 18, 22}
```

I know how to do this with an inefficient "loop through the cursor" solution, but I'm wondering if Postgres has a way to do a looping computation inline or a built-in distribution function that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` to create the running *n* for your formula. Use the `WITH ORDINALITY` option of `generate_series()` to have an ordinal number you can order the results by. Make sure you cast (at least) one operand of the division in your formula to `decimal` as otherwise integer division is used. Use `round()` to round the result. Then use `array_agg()` to build the array. Use `ORDER BY` for `array_agg()` to order the array elements by the ordinal number generate by `generate_series()`. To update each row you can use a subquery.

```
UPDATE my_table t
       SET vals = (SELECT array_agg(round(t.loval + (gs.n - 1) * ((t.hival - t.loval)::numeric / (t.valcount - 1))) ORDER BY gs.o)
                          FROM generate_series(1, t.valcount) WITH ORDINALITY gs (n, o));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bd2693e1de461f1a2db1ff0f339718d7)

Comment: The WITH ORDINALITY does not appear to be necessary in this case. I get the same results if I ditch it and ORDER BY n itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sets don't have an order. So it is necessary to explicitly order in SQL when one wants an order. I never found out if `generate_series()` somehow asserts the returned set to be in order anyway. It usually does return the result ordered but that may not be guaranteed. So to be safe I explicitly use `WITH ORDINALITY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the answer from the post you linked in this way:

```
update my_table
  set vals = array_append(array_prepend(loval,array(select (loval + (n-1) * ((hival - loval)::decimal / (valcount- 1)))::int 
             from generate_series(2, valcount-1) as n)),hival);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=532a368e2abf5f0474ec99e07e428219)**:

```
| loval | hival | valcount | vals            |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | --------------- |
| 3     | 22    | 6        | 3,7,11,14,18,22 |
```

`::decimal` will make sure that the division is done with floating numbers so that your second value is 7 instead of 6 with only integers.
`array_prepend` and `array_append` will add an element at the beginning and at the end of the array

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `generate_series()` and `array_agg()` like so:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (
         select array_agg(loval + (n - 1) * (hival - loval) / (valcount - 1) order by n)
         from generate_series(1, valcount) as d(n)
    ) vals
from t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mCkzDRyb3hwcH79S5Ep5yL/0)**:

```
| loval | hival | valcount | vals            |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | --------------- |
| 3     | 22    | 6        | 3,6,10,14,18,22 |
```